# How can I run a php script to update mysql database column based on some specific parameter?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have a database of over 1,50,000 entries. It has columns like state name, district name, office name etc etc. Now I want to update the entire database with the php `Soundex` for each row with its state name, district name, office name.
each row has a column of state_soundex, office_name_soundex and district_soundex.
I want to run a php script which will update the entire database like this -
it will take the state name and apply `soundex('state_name')` and put it into the state_soundex column and the same goes with district and office name.
This is what I have so far which does not work -

```
// database connection working alright

$query = "SELECT office_name, state, district FROM pincodes";
$result = mysqli_query($mysql, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $state_name = $row['state'];

    $soundex = soundex($state_name);

    $q = "UPDATE pincodes SET state_soundex =  '$soundex' WHERE state = '$state_name'";
    $r = mysqli_query($mysql, $q);

}
```

But it's not updating. Please help. I am not able to figure out how to do it.
I just need to run the script once and update it entirely. That's it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could probably do that in one sql statement, `UPDATE pincodes SET state_soundex=soundex(state)`

Comment: @RamRaider  What I want to achieve is that in case the user search for an office name and misspell it mysql doesn't return anything. So I want to store soundex for that and take the user input for the office name and match against the soundex_office_name. Like for my area, some people use "Bohru" as office name and some use "Baharu", the database has "baharu" as the value. But both of them have the same soundex. So matching against the soundex will give result incase user types "bohru".
Do you think it's a good idea or should I take any other approcah?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `soundex` in conjunction with `like` perhaps and maybe `levenshtein` should help - alternatively if you were to use a `datalist` on the search box input field with a list of KNOWN offices from which the user can select might be better / more reliable

Answer (score 2):

Rather than over complicate things with a loop and inner queries you can simply use one sql statement to accomplish the same thing.

```
$query = "UPDATE `pincodes` SET `state_soundex`=soundex(`state`)";
$result = mysqli_query( $mysql, $query );
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me that MySQL has this function.  The MySQL and PHP soundex implementations are not the same though.  The OP should be aware, in case it matters, that the soundex results of the same input string will be different.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ramraider. I spent over an hour overcomplicating things and not getting anywhere. Didn't know that mysql has this feature too.

Comment: @BeetleJuice What I want to achieve is that in case the user search for an office name and misspell it mysql doesn't return anything. So I want to store soundex for that and take the user input for the office name and match against the soundex_office_name. Like for my area, some people use "Bohru" as office name and some use "Baharu", the database has "baharu" as the value. But both of them have the same soundex. So matching against the soundex will give result incase user types "bohru".
Do you think it's a good idea or should I take any other approcah?
Thanks in advance.